# Trying to understand and reproduce Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I am currently trying to understand Pattern and Matcher a little bit more and found the following code:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            String.format("addPart%s(?<assembly>%s)\\+(?<amount>%s)%s(?<part>%s)",
                    InOutputStrings.COMMAND_SEPARATOR,
                    InOutputStrings.NAME_PATTERN,
                    InOutputStrings.NUMBER_PATTERN,
                    InOutputStrings.INNER_SEPARATOR,
                    InOutputStrings.NAME_PATTERN));

    private String assemblyName;
    private int amount;
    private String partName;

    ...

    assemblyName = matcher.group("assembly");
    amount = tryParse(matcher.group("amount"));
    partName = matcher.group("part");
```

whereby

```
    NAME_PATTERN("[a-zA-Z]+"),
    NUMBER_PATTERN("(?!(0[0-9]))[0-9]+"),
    COMMAND_SEPARATOR(" "),
    ARGUMENT_SEPARATOR(";"),
    INNER_SEPARATOR(":")
```

What would be a valid input here?

Could someone show me how this would look like for the input-pattern

"`add track <startPoint> -> <endPoint>`"?

I am working on a Command-line pattern and this would be a good way of implementing the input parsing.

Also, what is the meaning of `"?", "\\+" and "<assembly>"...`?

Comment: `String.format("add track%s(?<startPoint>%s) -> (?<endPoint>%s)", InOutputStrings.COMMAND_SEPARATOR,
                    InOutputStrings.POINT_PATTERN,
                    InOutputStrings.POINT_PATTERN));`  - Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be a valid input here?

`addPart foo+42:bar`

> ...how this would look like for the input-pattern...

`add track (?<startPoint>[a-zA-Z]+) -> (?<endPoint>[a-zA-Z]+)`

> ...what is the meaning of...

- `?!` is a [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `?<assembly>` is a [Named Capturing Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)
- `\\+` is a literal plus sign (not a RegEx operator)

Also note that `%s` is a variable reference for `String.format`. It is not a RegEx operator either.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Is it necessary or recommended to use %s for spaces?

Comment: The author of the code apparently wanted that space to be a variable. Note that all of the `InOutputStrings` could be hard-coded into the pattern rather than separated out.

Comment: Is that better coding style than just using spaces in the pattern?

Comment: It's purely a matter of taste and preference and whether you want the space to be configurable. There's no right or wrong answer.